# How to get a value from an optional map?

Tags: java, java-8, maps

I have a short question. How can I get a value from an optional map ?

In the foreach (fuelTypesFromDriveTrain.forEach ...) I want to extract values from the map:

- String value = fuelTypesMap.get(fuelTypeFromDriveTrain.getType());

But I don't know how to access them and I think the reason is that my map is an *Optional*. Any ideas ?

```
  // the map 
  final Optional<Map<String, String>> fuelTypesMap = extractAttributeElementValueMap(fuelTypeAttributes);

  final Set<FuelType> fuelTypesFromDriveTrain = getFuelTypesFromDriveTrain(driveTrain);

 if (refueling.getTypes().isEmpty() && !fuelTypesFromDriveTrain.isEmpty()) {
            Set<String> fuelTypesKeys = new HashSet<>();
            fuelTypesMap.map(Map::keySet)
                    .map(Collection::stream)
                    .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
                    .forEach(fuelTypeKey -> fuelTypesKeys.add(fuelTypeKey));

            fuelTypesFromDriveTrain.forEach(fuelTypeFromDriveTrain -> {
                if(fuelTypesKeys.contains(fuelTypeFromDriveTrain.getType())) {
                       String value = fuelTypesMap.get(fuelTypeFromDriveTrain.getType());
                       // I cannot obtain the value from the map
                     
                       refueling.getTypes().add(value);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: If you know it's not empty, you can use `get` to just get the map out. Otherwise, you can use `.map(m -> m.get(key))` to get an `Optional<String>`

Comment: @user Thank you!

Comment: You could also work easily with `Map<String, String>> definitiveFuelTypeMap = fuelTypesMap.orElse(Collections.emptyMap());` unless you want to mutate it. A question to ask yourself - what should be the behaviour if the Optional is not present and further if the key is not present in the Map.

Answer (score 0):

Check with below code

```
fuelTypesFromDriveTrain.forEach(fuelTypeFromDriveTrain -> {
            fuelTypesMap.map(dataMap->dataMap.get(fuelTypeFromDriveTrain.getType()))
                    .ifPresent(value->refueling.getTypes().add(value));
        });
```